# JSF for drawing graphs (not a chart, but a DAG) in HTML5

Tags: java, html, jsf, canvas, graph

I want to draw some nodes (might be substituted by small thumbnails) and connect them with lines. I also want to write some stuff at each node and make the nodes clickble. A click will then lead me to a new page with some other information.

My technology is set to Java webservers. Business logic is full off JPA, so I though using JSF is the right way to go.

Can this be done with HTML5 canvas and some nice new JSF component? I'm open to any suggestion, but it should be able to look pretty.

Dragging and dropping nodes would be cool as a future extension, but are not so important right now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I was looking for something like that too, but I've not found anything with JSF, only jQuery plugins. Here are two of the best: http://cytoscape.github.com/cytoscapeweb/ and http://jsplumb.org/jquery/stateMachineDemo.html

Comment: @StepTNT thanks, these two things look really nice, I will have to play around for a while to see if they're right for my purpose.

Comment: You're welcome! I think that this 2 plugins are the best that you can't find, and it must not be that hard using them with JSF :) Let me know what you're doing because I need to do something with them too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We create a Primefaces JSF component for graph visualization. Rendering is done using CytoscapeWeb (flash version).

May be we will create adapters for the new CytoscapeWeb library (HTML5 and JQuery)

Component has been created for learn Primefaces component development and it need some improvements but i hope it will help you.

Links for demos and download are available from [Primefaces Forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=19316&p=81859#p81858)

---

2012/11/12: Finally we created new adapters for the CytoscapeWeb 2 library (HTML5 and JQuery) and a new version named Graphvis2 is available.

Online Demos:

- http://www.sysord.com/Sysord/ressource_graphvis2_demo_clientSideEvents.jsf
- http://www.sysord.com/Sysord/ressource_graphvis2_demo_ajaxBehaviors.jsf
- http://www.sysord.com/Sysord/ressource_graphvis2_demo_dijkstra.jsf

Download:
https://github.com/sysord/Graphvis

Answer (score 0):

I like a lot the charts of primefaces http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/lineChart.jsf. And they are really easy to use.

Comment: He was asking about a DAG (Directed acyclic graph), not a chart